# history.js + Has anyone Got HTML4 Support Working - Anyone?

Tags: jquery, history.js

I've spent a couple of days trying to get history.js to work on HTML4 browsers.

I've gone through all the doco a few times and I can't see to get around error messages that IE throws up - you can see here: http://www.salesmelbourne.com (page1,page2 etc)

I've also gone through the list of **showcase websites** that are ment to have history.js working and the **vast majority of them don't even use the plugin** and none have html4 support working:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Showcase

Finally I've written to the written/owner without any luck.

Thus I wanted to finally ask if anyone has got history.js HTML4 support to work or is it just a nice idea that doesn't really work... I'm assuming the later but wanted to ask.

If you have got it working please post a URL here so I can have a look at the source.

thx

Comment: Well, I am integrating it and I can't say it's compatible with HTML4 browsers yet... IE8 + IE9 are failing on the calls History.go(-2), they're only getting one event fired when it should be two.
Plus there are external accessible methods like getStateId() that regenerates the ID which becomes then different than the real ID of the current state... but that's nothing in comparison of the problem of the events I am getting with History.go(n).